# What can I do to fix a "could not resolve host: mirrors.fedoraproject.org" when applying system updates?

Tags: fedora, package-management, upgrade, mirror

This is now the second day of getting this error message when I attempt to download and install system updates. There are 25 updates, including an OS update, waiting to be installed.

> Detailed errors from the package manager follow:
>
> cannot download
>   Packages/j/java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.60-14.b27.fc23.i686.rpm
>   to /var/cache/PackageKit/metadata/fedora/packages/: Curl error (6):
>   Couldn't resolve host name for
>   https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-23&arch=x86_64
>   [Could not resolve host: mirrors.fedoraproject.org]

I've been able to install various packages, but not the system updates. Is there anything else that I can try locally?

When I go to https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-23&arch=x86_64 or mirrors.fedoraproject.org in a browser, the URLs resolve. It is only when doing a system update that it fails.

The contents of my `/etc/resolv.conf` file:

> `# Generated by NetworkManager`
>
> `search hsd1.ma.comcast.net`
>
> `nameserver 75.75.75.75`
>
> `nameserver 75.75.76.76`
>
> `nameserver 2001:558:feed::1`
>
> `# NOTE: the libc resolver may not support more than 3 nameservers.`
>
> `# The nameservers listed below may not be recognized.`
>
> `nameserver 2001:558:feed::2`

The output of `sudo ifconfig -a`:

> enp0s25: flags=4099  mtu 1500
>
> ```
>     ether 00:24:7e:e1:89:5b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
>
>     RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>
>     RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>
>     TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>
>     TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
>
>     device interrupt 20  memory 0xfc600000-fc620000
> ```
>
> lo: flags=73  mtu 65536
>
> ```
>     inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
>
>     inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
>
>     loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
>
>     RX packets 24  bytes 2064 (2.0 KiB)
>
>     RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>
>     TX packets 24  bytes 2064 (2.0 KiB)
>
>     TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
> ```
>
> virbr0: flags=4099  mtu 1500
>
> ```
>     inet 192.168.124.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.124.255
>
>     ether 52:54:00:1d:e6:d9  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
>
>     RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>
>     RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>
>     TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>
>     TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
> ```
>
> virbr0-nic: flags=4098  mtu 1500
>
> ```
>     ether 52:54:00:1d:e6:d9  txqueuelen 500  (Ethernet)
>
>     RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>
>     RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>
>     TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>
>     TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
> ```
>
> wlp3s0: flags=4163  mtu 1500
>
> ```
>     inet 10.0.0.142  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
>
>     inet6 2601:184:4500:bff5:221:6aff:fe8b:fbbc  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
>
>     inet6 fe80::221:6aff:fe8b:fbbc  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
>
>     inet6 2601:184:4500:bff5::154d  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
>
>     ether 00:21:6a:8b:fb:bc  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
>
>     RX packets 17231  bytes 9568612 (9.1 MiB)
>
>     RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>
>     TX packets 13742  bytes 2820399 (2.6 MiB)
>
>     TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
> ```

Comment: I am resolving it. what is your /etc/resolv.conf?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Let me edit that the contents of /etc/resolv.conf into my question. If I go there in a browser (to https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-23&arch=x86_64 or to mirrors.fedoraproject.org), it resolves. It only doesn't resolve in the software update tool.

Comment: would you post "sudo ifconfig -a" please?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Added.

Comment: multi-network machine, IPv6... an interesting test could be deactivating IPv6  temporarily and testing the situation to rule that out. "sudo netstat -nr"?

Comment: @Rui I'm about to head out fot holidays. I'll be following up early next week, at the latest.